# connection reset on my websphere

Tags: connection, websphere, httpurlconnection, reset, socketexception

I'm trying to connect to a host. The error "connection reset" always occurs in the websphere.
As a self-written Java project without websphere it works with the identical code. The
error does not occur. I suspect that the websphere and the ciphersuite "TLS ... SHA386" don't
work together. But when setting the socket no error occurs. Can someone help me?

I work with:
websphere v8.5.5.11
java-sdk 1.8.64_bundled

and here my Java-Code:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ClientStart {

@PostConstruct
public void startClient(){

    try {
        testHttp();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



void testHttp() throws Exception {

    String token24h = "eyJhbGci ... 95BBo7PVej8uXdw9sA";
    String url = "https:// ... /apserver/api/products/111234568408/packs/U1Q0MUFHUEdHMExXQUo=?ctx=f2a98d0d-9d06-45e3-8f58-87f9d3cfcb06&lot=QlRFNEdBTQ==&exp=310822&pcs=PPN&sid=07758c03-d265-454d-8544-6d0e2ca29d53";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();
sslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
});     

  con.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);       

  //create Request-Header aufbauen
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token24h);
  con.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL,"no-cache");
  con.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,"application/json");
  con.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING,"application/json");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    //TODO other things

}
```

After step con.getResponseCode() appears this Stacktrace

[31.03.18 16:49:09:269 CEST] 00000054 SystemErr     R java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
[31.03.18 16:49:09:269 CEST] 00000054 SystemErr     R   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:220)
[31.03.18 16:49:09:285 CEST] 00000054 SystemErr     R   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
[31.03.18 16:49:09:285 CEST] 00000054 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:79)
[31.03.18 16:49:09:285 CEST] 00000054 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:182)

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest investigating how the handshakes differ in the two environments.

Comment: Because of how Websphere's custom SSLSocketFactory works you could be ending up with different instances of the SocketFactory.  Can you try changing `SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();  to `SSLSocket sslsocket = socketFactory.createSocket();`

Comment: Hi, I found the solution in my websphere. It was a little bit tricky:

1. The chipers was outdated. I updated two files in Java: local_policy.jar and us_export_policy. jar. Now I can get 'SSL_ ... SHA386' in my program.

2. I added the signer certificat with export from the firefox and imported into websphere

3. The FIPS has been activated

And now, my little wbapp runs smoothly. Juchu!